# Why is an apparently noop assignment significant in this one weird JS code snippet?

Tags: javascript, this, lodash, prototypal-inheritance

See: http://jsbin.com/gapeya/edit?js,console

In the above code, why does assigning `this.a` to `this.a` make the property `a` available on the `new`'d object?

Or to phrase it another way; why is the prototypical property `a` not ["enumerable"](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) unless explicitly assigned?

PS: I'm aware that this is probably a case of *Doing It Wrong*, but am nonetheless confused by this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Properties that are "part of the prototype chain" are not enumerable. Because the property `a` in my question was added to `A` via `A.prototype`, I guess that makes it non-enumerable.

Job done, thanks SO!

See: http://zduck.com/2013/non-enumerable-properties-in-javascript/

Comment: JSBin updated my crappy solution to the get behaviour I wanted http://jsbin.com/juyige/edit?js,console